# Connect to Azure AD from C# via provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningWebService.svc service

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

A can use the ProvisioningWebService.IProvisioningWebService from ProvisioningWebService Service (https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningWebService.svc). 
I add to my project wsdl. In web.config generated:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="External">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningWebService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="External" contract="ProvisioningWebService.IProvisioningWebService"
    name="External">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Get client:

```
var provisioningWebServiceService = new ProvisioningWebServiceClient("External");
```

how i can add **UserIdentityHeader**,**LiveToken**, and **BecContext** to client?
Request from powershell is fine. Request from c# bad. I have error **"The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason."**